# Scala: Read innermap of map based on multiple key values using find() or filter()

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I have 3 json's as below, from Json 1 object I need to get value of "device-name" from "device" map and if "device" map is not there then I need to get value of "device-name" from "interface" map.

From Json 2 object I need to get value of "device-name" from "interface" map and from Json 3 object I need to get value of "segment-device-name" from "segment" map.

I may get any of these 3 json's from frontend, how  to achieve this in an elegant way in Scala by converting json to map and using minimum number of lines, like by using find() or filter() functions of Scala map

I am using `org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse(request.getContent).extract[Map[String, Any]]` to convert json to map, as innermap may be map again I use Any
Json 1:

```
{
  "device": {
    "device-name": "scala",
    "payment" : {
       "test": "x"
     }
   },
  "interface": {
    "device-name": "java"
  }
}
```

Json 2:

```
{
  "interface": {
    "device-name": "java"
  }
}
```

Json 3:

```
{
  "segment": {
    "segment-device-name": "java"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you parse instead as `Map[String, Map[String, String]]` then you can, for Map m ...

```
val keys = List(
  ("device", "device-name"),
  ("interface", "device-name"),
  ("segment", "segment-device-name")
)
val ans = for {
  (ko, ki) <- keys
  v <- m.get(ko)  // get inner map if exists, else go to next k, v pair
} yield v(ki)

ans(0)  //  0 index ensures we get "device" if exists before "interface"
```

This will desugar to map and flatMap as ...

```
val ans = keys.flatMap(case (ko, ki) => m.get(ko).map(v => v(ki)))
```

**NOT TESTED**

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I edited question to match with my actual requirement, can you please provide solution for above requirement